# Laravel PayPal CORS

Tags: laravel, paypal, fetch, url-scheme

I'm using Laravel to integrate with PayPal. H

The problem is that when I click on the PayPal JS button I get CORS error on my console.

I've done something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors).

Also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058751/laravel-5-8-cors-being-blocked-even-when-enabled). But when I check cors.php, it was already enabled:

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135127/laravel-angularjs-cors-using-barryvdh-laravel-cors), and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283885/paypal-cors-error) but had no luck. Didn't found much code base myself in, so I decided to make a post.

My cors.php has to following line:

```
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
```

This is my CORS middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    }
}
```

I've added this to my Kernel.php, under $routeMiddleware:

```
'CORS' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
```

This is my routes:

```
Route::get('/test', [Controller::class, 'test'])->middleware('CORS');
```

And this is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CreateOrder;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->afterFilter(function(){

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        });
    }

    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function test()
    {
        return serialize(CreateOrder::createOrder(true));
    }
}
```

But I still get the same CORS error:

[image: error]

And this is my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-500{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:#6b7280;color:rgba(107,114,128,var(--tw-text-opacity))}}
        </style>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">

        <script
          src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=token&currency=BRL"> // Required. Replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID.
        </script>

        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

        <script>
          paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function() {
              return fetch('localhost:80/test', {
              method: 'get',
              headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json'
              }
              }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
              }).then(function(data) {
                return data.id; // Use the key sent by your server's response, ex. 'id' or 'token'
              });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
              return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
              });
            }
          }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `localhost:80/test`

> CORS request not http

You want `http://localhost:80/test` or `http://localhost/test`